# I'm using gmail server to send email in my xampp lite server, but i'm not recieving any emails

Tags: php, email, gmail, xampp, mail-server

basically i followed this tutorial:

http://egrasp.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/sending-email-in-php-using-xampp-lite-1-7-3-on-windows/

its a tutorial on how to setup gmail as your mail server in xampp lite.  I followed all the steps exactly, even tested the mail function in php and says its been sent or no error warnings basically, but yet I do not recieve any email...what else do i need to do?

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: Just because PHP says the mail was sent doesn't mean it was. What PHP is telling you is that it dropped the envelope into the mailbox. The postal service might lose the mail, the receiving end might drop it in the trash, blah blah blah blah. Never trust PHP when it comes to email.

Comment: Show us the PHP code you use to send mails. How do you check for PHP errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your ISP is blocking the normal SMTP ports (many do this to prevent spamming). Try using the alternate port `587` provided by Google. See [this help article](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799) from Google support.